# ViewPager with Fragments inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I am trying to create a news app which intakes data from a server and displays it onto a `recyclerView`. An item inside the `recyclerView` consists of a `CardView` containing a `ViewPager` and a `TextView`. I want the `ViewPager` to initially show the image of the news, and on swiping the `Viewpager`, the description of the news. However only the fragments inside the `Viewpager` of the first `CardView` seems to inflate. Please Help

```
class ViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private final LayoutInflater inflator;
    Context context;
     List<FeedItem> items=new ArrayList<>();
    static String dummy1;
    static String dummy2;
    static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    static SwipeAdapter adapter;

    public ViewAdapter(Context context, List<FeedItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        inflator=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        fragmentManager=((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
        adapter=new SwipeAdapter(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view_feed;
        view_feed=inflator.inflate(R.layout.feed_row,null,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view_feed);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
             holder.title.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
        dummy1=items.get(position).getThumbnail();
        dummy2=items.get(position).getDescription();
             LoadView(holder.container,position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageButton btn_heart;
        ImageButton btn_share;
        ImageButton btn_mark;
        ViewPager container;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title=itemView.findViewById(R.id.feed_title);
            btn_heart=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_heart);
            btn_mark=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_bookmark);
            btn_share=itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_share);
            container=itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        }
    }

    void LoadView(ViewPager viewPager,int position) {
        Fragment fragment1=new Screen1();
        Fragment fragment2=new Screen2();
        adapter.addMember(fragment1);
        adapter.addMember(fragment2);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

`dummy1` and `dummy2` are strings to take in data from the `OnBindViewer` and provide it to the two fragments of the `Viewpager` of corresponding position.
`Addmember` is a method inside the `FragmentPagerAdapter` to add the fragment to the list of fragments provided to the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.